# Preventing Bootstrap from adjusting margin width until necessary

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I love Bootstrap, it's great, but it keeps trying to bringing my `.span3` class elements closer and closer together when I like their current width.  How can I tell Bootstrap to chill out, until my elements using the `.span3` class need to be adjusted?  Lets say that when the screen size 1170px wide or greater everything is spaced fine, however, when I reach somewhere around 980px wide, Bootstrap brings everything in a little bit closer, but I don't need it to.  How can I tell Bootstrap to chill out with the adjustments, until screen size reaches 767px or so.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FvEx/1/) for you fine geniuses as well.

As far as I can tell, a media query would be the best call, something like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .span3: chill out;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .span3: do yo thang;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is part of Bootstrap's responsiveness. At regular sizes the gutters between the grid columns are at 20px, but at huge screen widths (1200px+) it loosens the gutters to 30px.

**1) If you're editing the LESS files manually**

Look in "variables.less" for this line.

```
@gridGutterWidth768:      20px;
```

Change it to 30px. Recompile LESS.

**2) If you're creating an override CSS file**

Include this in your custom CSS file, and make sure it's included/imported after bootstrap.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
  [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```